# Highcharts: set constant X-axis zoom-range while getting live streaming data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to draw points that have come in the past minute/hour without drawing initial graph immediately like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgyuypkn/)?

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: 0,
            max: 9
        },
        ...
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        // Add new point
        chart.series[0].addPoint(5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25));
        // Update x-axis range
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[0].dataMax-9, chart.xAxis[0].dataMax);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Example: There are some data for the whole day. But I want to show data only for an hour at once. If it's less then hour then scale doesn't change.

Comment: Could you ellaborate your question including more details?